# Windows can't connect to Linux Minecraft LAN

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I have read a lot of stuff on here & elsewhere, but still not getting any joy.

I am running Linux Mint 17. The rest of my family are on Windows 7.  I can join their LAN worlds, but they can't connect to mine.

I have tried editing the hosts file as in [Can't set up a local LAN server on Minecraft 12w25a?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74400/cant-set-up-a-local-lan-server-on-minecraft-12w25a) et al, but that hasn't helped.
My hosts file now looks like this:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX MYPC
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     MYPC localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

(My IP address & pc name are definitely correct in the real world)

I have run UFW commands to open port 25565 thus: (https://computerobz.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/how-to-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu/)

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Once that rule has been added then we can enable the firewall:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Now we need to enable the other ports we are going to be using. Minecraft runs on a default port of 25565. Run the following command to add the port.

```
sudo ufw allow 25565
```

Check the Firewall status to make sure all is setup right:

```
sudo ufw status
```

25565 is set to "allow"

The server & port shows up on the Windows PC, just times out.

Any ideas where I go from here please?

Comment: Have you verified that your port is actually open on the router level? Try going to canyouseeme.org and enter your port number, and check.

Comment: @Zymus Port forwarding will probably not help, because they are all already on the same network, since they're using LAN.

Comment: I'm very sketchy on port forwarding etc - I did understand that being on a LAN only, everything took place behind the router/firewall.  If I go to canyouseemee I can see an IP address that I don't recognise & port 80

Comment: @Ghalid, even within the local network, the connection goes through the router. If the machine that's hosting the server isn't allowed access through that port, it will still be blocked. The only exception would be if the two machines are literally networked together through one ethernet cable.

Comment: @Zymus I believe I have hosted a LAN before without port-forwarding, and others were able to connect to it.

Comment: @MrTrog, that IP is YOUR public IP address. Replace port 80 with 25565 and hit check.

Comment: @MrTrog, are you running a mod that allows you to choose your LAN port? Because in my experience, when you open a LAN, it has a different port each time in vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: @MrTrog, can you update your post with the output of `sudo ufw status`?

Comment: ...but the router will let me join a W7 pc LAN game so it's letting local stuff through one way & not the other?

Comment: @Zymus ufw status is too long 25565 is allow from anywhere - anything else to look for/post?

Comment: @:Ghalid - vanilla. Ports change each time, but are shown on the W7 pc (which is next to mine)

Comment: Then port forwarding `25565` shouldn't affect anything since you're not using that port - try using `sudo ufw allow 25565` but replace `25565` with the correct port that Minecraft outputs in chat when you "Open to LAN".

Comment: @Ghalid That did it, thank you.  Are there implications if I keep running ufw allow each time? Should I shut 25565?

Comment: @MrTrog You're essentially punching a hole through your firewall, so you might want to delete the rule when you're done if you would like, or you can also only limit the rule to your local network.

Comment: @MrTrog If you don't use `25565` for anything, you can shut that rule too.

Answer (score 5):

Opening Minecraft to LAN does **not** use the port `25565`; instead it uses a different port each time. You can use

```
sudo ufw allow <port>
```

to open the port and change `<port>` with the port that Minecraft chose when opening to LAN. Or, if you want convenience, you can allow any connections from your local network here(assuming you trust everyone in your network... which you probably should!)

```
ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any
```

Change `192.168.0.0/24` to the IP range for your network.

Source: [Ubuntu UFW Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)
specifically:

> Allow by Subnet
>
> You may use a net mask :
>
> sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 Allow by specific port and IP
>   address
>
> sudo ufw allow from  to  port 
>   example: allow IP address 192.168.0.4 access to port 22 for all
>   protocols
>
> sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.4 to any port 22